# Android excessive SurfaceFlinger login for simple Cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, samsung-mobile

I have a very basic Cordova app rendering a small react site (the most basic one, created with create-react-app). This features a react svg logo spinning around in a slow animation.

When running this app and checking the logs with `adb logat`, I constantly get the following sequence:

```
D/SurfaceFlinger(  279): FPS : 60.19
W/SurfaceFlinger(  279): Fail to Open /sys/devices/platform/gpusysfs/fps
```

I don't really think this problem is related to my app specifically, but it still bugs me. Anything to do about it?

I'm running on a Samsung GT-I9505 with Android 5.0.1.

Comment: Im having the same problem in a cordova app when i try to open a specific website on innappbrowser, have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is affecting all Samsung GT-I95XX.

```
D/SurfaceFlinger: FPS : 15.99
W/SurfaceFlinger: Fail to Open /sys/devices/platform/gpusysfs/fps
    TIMA: QCOM_send_command--int8_t QCOM_send_command(TIMA_handle_t, void*, uint32_t, void*, uint32_t, uint32_t)
    rsp_len = 1008 rcvd_data_len = 1040, self_calculate_len=1040
```

I think it's linked [to a security issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/project-zero/issues/detail?id=969) which caused a buffer Overflow.
Google (laginimaineb) said it's fixed now, but the service "SurfaceFlinger" is still trying to access it, in a infinite loop. 
And it eats a lot of battery too...